# JXLS - how to write data to workbook in batches

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi, export-to-excel, jxls

I have to implement export of users into XLS. After a little research JXLS came up as simple solution, but there is one problem. I want to avoid OutOfMemory exception, so I have to fetch users and write them to Excel in chunks, and I don't know how to do that with JXLS.

Here is my code (based on solutions found all over the Internet):

```
try {
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("/Users/javaer/Documents/xlsx/templates/users_template.xlsx"));
        SelectSheetsForStreamingPoiTransformer transformer = new SelectSheetsForStreamingPoiTransformer(workbook);
        transformer.setDataSheetsToUseStreaming(Set.of("Template"));

        List<User> users = userRepository.findAcceptedBetLogs(filter);

        Context context = new PoiContext();
        context.getConfig().setIsFormulaProcessingRequired(false);
        context.putVar("users", users);

        AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XlsCommentAreaBuilder(transformer);
        List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();
        Area xlsArea = xlsAreaList.get(0);
        xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Template!A1"), context);

        transformer.getWorkbook().write(fileOutputStream);
        transformer.getWorkbook().close();
        transformer.dispose();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

So, here I have to fetch all users into list, and then pass that list to xlsArea which is not good enough in my case.

Comment: You need to use an SXSSF transformer like in https://github.com/jxlsteam/jxls/blob/master/jxls-poi/src/test/java/org/jxls/examples/stress/SxssfDemo.java

Comment: @PJFanning tnx for reply. I saw those examples before I posted question here, but I can't see solution for my problems in those examples. I have to fetch "departments" in chunks and write them to workbook in chunks. For example, I want to fetch 1000 rows in chunks of 100 rows and write them to workbook in chunks. I don't want to have all of 1000 items in memory at once.